# Groovy : Convert String / Map to JSONObject

Tags: json, groovy

```
   def stringJson =  '''{"Student": {"Name": "","age":}}'''
```

`def mapJson = ["Student": ["Name": "","age": ]]`

I need output as  org.json.simple.JSONObject

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I had added my answer which is working fine! Check that dude! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can parse json string to map and then create **org.json.simple.JSONObject** instance from this map:

```
//org.json.simple.JSONObject dependency
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='com.googlecode.json-simple', module='json-simple', version='1.1')
)

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import org.json.simple.JSONObject

def stringJson =  '''{"Student": {"Name": "","age": null}}'''

//parse json string to map
Map json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(stringJson)
//build JSONObject instance from map
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer.

`import org.json.simple.JSONObject`

`import groovy.json.JsonSlurper`

`def stringJson =  '''{"Student": {"Name": "","age":""}}'''`

`def resultJson =new JsonSlurper().parseText(stringJson)`

`JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(resultJson)`

`println jsonObject`